# Как добавить form в вкладку tabControl? Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Я нашел в интернете такой код но он добавляет по индексу но мне нужно с добавлением и переводом на новую вкладку для пользователя.

```
Forms.Customers frm = new Forms.Customers();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.Visible = true;
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(frm)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796334/embed-a-form-onto-a-tabcontrol-in-windows-forms
я нашел он внизу ответ

```
FormChild frmChild = new FormChild();
AddNewTab(frmChild);
Copy this Function to your code:

private void AddNewTab(Form frm)
{

    TabPage tab = new TabPage(frm.Text);

    frm.TopLevel = false;

    frm.Parent = tab;

    frm.Visible = true;

    tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab);

    frm.Location = new Point((tab.Width - frm.Width) / 2, (tab.Height - frm.Height) / 2);

    tabControl.SelectedTab = tab;

}
```